# Request's content-type header contains more than the MIME type, why?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I noticed that sometimes the `content-type` header of a request (e.g., made by Firefox) does not only contain information on the MIME type, but also on the encoding.

E.g., when sending JSON using AJAX instead of

```
application/json
```

(what I expected) Firefox sent:

```
application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I have a number of questions on this behavior:

1. What other "parameters" (or "options", or whatever you call the `charset` value) could happen?
2. Will `application/json` always come first, or may the values appear in random order (i.e., could it also be `charset=UTF-8; application/json`)?
3. Is the separator always a `;`?
4. What is the canonical way of testing for a specific MIME type? Just comparing the header doesn't work, obviously. Any hints? Is there something better than `contentType === 'application/json || contentType.startsWith('application/json;')`?

PS: For question #4, I created a separate question. See [Get an entire string or a substring, depending on a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947729/get-an-entire-string-or-a-substring-depending-on-a-specific-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7)

> 3.7 Media Types
>
> HTTP uses Internet Media Types [17] in the Content-Type (section
>   14.17) and Accept (section 14.1) header fields in order to provide open and extensible data typing and type negotiation.
>
> ```
>    media-type     = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )
>    type           = token
>    subtype        = token Parameters MAY follow the type/subtype in the form of attribute/value pairs (as defined in section 3.6).
> ```

So

1. There is no fixed list of possible values
2. Yes, type should come first
3. The delimiter is `;`

Comment: Great, this perfectly answers my question. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Something that's worth mentioning: the RFC 2616 is dead. Don't use it. Instead point to the new RFC 7231. [RFC 7231](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231)