# Get an entire string or a substring, depending on a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string-comparison

I have a string that contains a MIME type, say `application/json`. Now I want to compare this against an actual HTTP header, in this case `content-type`.

If the header contains the MIME type, then it's as easy as:

```
if (mimeType === contentType) { ... }
```

Unfortunately, the header *may* contain additional parameters. They always come after the value I'm interested in, and they are separated from it by a `;`. E.g., it could be `application/json; charset=UTF-8`.

So now basically I need to run:

```
if (mimeType === contentType.substring(0, contentType.indexOf(';'))) { ... }
```

The problem is that the first case still can happen, so now we have:

```
if (mimeType === contentType ||
    mimeType === contentType.substring(0, contentType.indexOf(';'))) { ... }
```

Things start to get lengthy…

I could think of comparing them using

```
if (mimeType === contentType.substring(0, mimeType.length)) { ...}
```

but this would also successfully match the value `application/jsonformatter` (which is not desired).

So, to cut a long story short: Is there a better way to compare these values than my lengthy `if` described above, e.g. using a regular expression?

Basically I'm thinking of an expression that shortens the header if necessary according to the following rules:

- If it contains a semicolon, return the part before it.
- If it doesn't contain a semicolon, return everything.

What is the most effective way of writing this?

Comment: The type will end at whitespace, end of line or ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a standard parsing module like `media-typer`, which Express uses in its middleware.

```
var typer = require('media-typer');

var obj = typer.parse(contentType);
if (obj.type === 'application' && obj.subtype === 'json'){
    // Success
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was originally looking for a module like this, but I wasn't able to find one. Thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex match:

```
if ( mimeType.match(/^application\/json(?= *;|$)/i) ) {
    // matched
}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eX6zX1/2)

Here `(?= *;|$)` is positive lookahead that will make sure that searched string `application/json` is either followed by optional spaces and `;` OR else it is the only string in the input.

Comment: The RFC allows OWS between the end of the type and the first `;` E.g `app/foo ; k=v`